# How to parse a simple JSON string to a DataSet with Json.Net

Tags: json, c#-4.0, json.net

I have tried just about everything I can think of to try to parse this JSON string using the JSON.net library, but I keep getting an error that says "additional text after string deserialize".  Does anyone have any ideas as to what might be going wrong?

Here is the JSON string I have:

```
{"w_vendor":["914115361","914115361","914115361","914115361","914115361","914115361","914115361","914115361","914115361","914115361","914115361","914115361","914115361","914115361","914115361","914115361","914115361","914115361","914115361","914115361","914115361","914115361","914115361","914115361","914115361","914115361","914115361","914115361","914115361","914115361","914115361","914115361","914115361","914115361","914115361","914115361"]}
```

Here is the code I'm using to try to parse it:

```
var pdfValue = Request["pdfValue"];
string OutputCacheLocation = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pdfValue);
DataSet dataset = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(pdfValue);

DataTable datatable = dataset.Tables["table1"];

Response.Write(datatable.Rows.Count);
```

Does anyone see the additional text the error refers to?  I can't see it, and the JSON just won't parse.  I'm about ready to give up and parse it manually myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of deserializing to a `DataSet`, have you considered creating a custom class for your data and deserializing to that instead?  It might be a little more straightforward to work with.

For example, if you define a class like this:

```
class Data
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName="w_vendor")]
    public List<string> Values { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize like this:

```
string json = @"{""w_vendor"":[""914115361"",""914115361"",""914115361"",""914115361"",""914115361"",""914115361"",""914115361"",""914115361"",""914115361"",""914115361"",""914115361"",""914115361"",""914115361"",""914115361"",""914115361"",""914115361"",""914115361"",""914115361"",""914115361"",""914115361"",""914115361"",""914115361"",""914115361"",""914115361"",""914115361"",""914115361"",""914115361"",""914115361"",""914115361"",""914115361"",""914115361"",""914115361"",""914115361"",""914115361"",""914115361"",""914115361""]}";

var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);

Response.Write(data.Values.Count);
```

**EDIT**

The reason it didn't work the way you had it is because your data doesn't conform to the structure it would need to in order to deserialize into a `DataSet`.  If you take a look at the [example from the documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/DeserializeDataSet.htm), the data would need to be structured like this:

```
{
    "table1" : 
    [
        {
            "column1" : "value1",
            "column2" : "value2"
        },
        {
            "column1" : "value3",
            "column2" : "value4"
        }            
    ],
    "table2" : 
    [
        {
            "column1" : "value1",
            "column2" : "value2"
        },
        {
            "column1" : "value3",
            "column2" : "value4"
        }            
    ]
}
```

Specifically, the outer object contains properties which represent tables.  The property names correspond to the names of the tables, and the values are arrays of *objects* where each object represents one row in the table.  The objects' properties correspond to the column names, and their values are the row data.

In your data, the outer object contains a property whose value is an array of simple strings, not objects.  So this can't be turned into a table because JSON.NET can't determine the column names.  Also, the name of the table for your data would have been `w_vendor`, not `table1`.

Comment: that worked and thank you but i dont understand what i was doing wrong to being with. Thanks a million for your response!

Comment: I edited my answer to give an explanation on why it didn't work the way you had it.

Comment: perfect sense Brian thanks for that explanation. I totally get it now! you are the MAN!